# NFC class' onNewIntent always runs after 3rd scan

Tags: android, nfc

I have a Activity that captures data from an NFC tag. In order for the contents of the tag to be read, i have to scan the tag 3 times.

I would like the contents of the tag to be extracted on the first scan.

On the first scan the activity seems to go into the following lifecycle methods:

onCreate -> onResume -> enableForegroundMode()

on the second scan:

onPause -> disableForegroundMode() -> onCreate -> onResume -> enableForegroundMode()

then on the final 3rd scan:

onPause -> disableForegroundMode() -> onNewIntent

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and why i have to always scan 3 times?

Below is my class and the stacktrace

thanks in advance

```
public class NfcActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = NfcActivity.class.getName();

    protected NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    protected PendingIntent nfcPendingIntent;

    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;

    Parcelable[] messages;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nfcactivitylayout);
        Log.e(TAG, "oncreate");
        // initialize NFC
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    public void enableForegroundMode() {
        Log.e(TAG, "enableForegroundMode");

        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED); // filter for all
        IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] {tagDetected};
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
    }

    public void disableForegroundMode() {
        Log.e(TAG, "disableForegroundMode");

        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onNewIntent");

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {          
            //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

            //textView.setText("Hello NFC!");

            messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (messages != null) {
                setContentView(R.layout.successfulnfc);

                Log.e(TAG, "Found " + messages.length + " NDEF messages"); // is almost always just one

                vibrate(); // signal found messages :-)



                initHandler();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,  2000);




            }
        } else {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");

        super.onResume();

        enableForegroundMode();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");

        super.onPause();

        disableForegroundMode();

        if(handler != null){
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }

    private void vibrate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "vibrate");

        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
        vibe.vibrate(500);
    }





}
```

.

```
01-05 12:56:48.849: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): oncreate
01-05 12:56:48.859: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): onResume
01-05 12:56:48.859: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): enableForegroundMode
01-05 12:56:50.099: E/wpa_supplicant(1113): send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 32
01-05 12:56:50.099: E/wpa_supplicant(1113): send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 50
01-05 12:56:50.099: E/wpa_supplicant(1113): send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 32
01-05 12:56:50.099: E/wpa_supplicant(1113): send_and_recv error 0 - cmd 50
01-05 12:56:50.699: E/MP-Decision(1724): Update arg 1
01-05 12:56:52.679: E/MP-Decision(1724): Update arg 2
01-05 12:56:52.699: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): onPause
01-05 12:56:52.699: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): disableForegroundMode
01-05 12:56:52.719: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): oncreate
01-05 12:56:52.719: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): onResume
01-05 12:56:52.719: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): enableForegroundMode
01-05 12:56:53.689: E/MP-Decision(1724): Update arg 1
01-05 12:56:55.009: E/MP-Decision(1724): Update arg 2
01-05 12:56:55.009: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): onPause
01-05 12:56:55.009: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): disableForegroundMode
01-05 12:56:55.019: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): onNewIntent
01-05 12:56:55.059: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): Found 1 NDEF messages
01-05 12:56:55.059: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): vibrate
01-05 12:56:55.059: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): onResume
01-05 12:56:55.059: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): enableForegroundMode
01-05 12:56:56.009: E/MP-Decision(1724): Update arg 1
01-05 12:56:57.059: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): about to process tag
01-05 12:56:57.089: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): Found 1 records in message 0
01-05 12:56:57.089: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362):  Record #0 is of class TextRecord
01-05 12:56:57.099: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): payload = 1,10,1074,Kelly Waugh
01-05 12:56:57.109: E/MP-Decision(1724): Update arg 2
01-05 12:56:57.129: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): onPause
01-05 12:56:57.129: E/com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcActivity(12362): disableForegroundMode
```

.

```
<activity
    android:name=".NfcActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>


        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[Edit1]

```
Intent i;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nfcactivitylayout);
        Log.e(TAG, "oncreate");
        // initialize NFC
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

        i = getIntent();

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(i.getAction())) {           
            //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

            //textView.setText("Hello NFC!");

            messages = i.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (messages != null) {
                setContentView(R.layout.successfulnfc);

                Log.e(TAG, "Found " + messages.length + " NDEF messages"); // is almost always just one

                vibrate(); // signal found messages :-)



                initHandler();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,  2000);




            }
        } else {
            // ignore
        }


    }
```

[Edit 3]

```
public class NfcActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = NfcActivity.class.getName();

    protected NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    protected PendingIntent nfcPendingIntent;

    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;

    Parcelable[] messages;

    Intent i;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nfcactivitylayout);
        Log.e(TAG, "oncreate");
        // initialize NFC
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

        i = getIntent();

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(i.getAction())) {          
            //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

            //textView.setText("Hello NFC!");

            messages = i.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (messages != null) {
                setContentView(R.layout.successfulnfc);

                Log.e(TAG, "Found " + messages.length + " NDEF messages"); // is almost always just one

                vibrate(); // signal found messages :-)



                initHandler();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,  2000);




            }
        } else {
            // ignore
        }


    }

    public void enableForegroundMode() {
        Log.e(TAG, "enableForegroundMode");

        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED); // filter for all
        IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] {tagDetected};
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
    }

    public void disableForegroundMode() {
        Log.e(TAG, "disableForegroundMode");

        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onNewIntent");

        Intent processPayloadIntent = new Intent(NfcActivity.this, NfcscannerActivity.class);

        processPayloadIntent.setAction("QRCODE_ACTION"); 
        processPayloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(processPayloadIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");

        super.onResume();

        enableForegroundMode();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");

        super.onPause();

        disableForegroundMode();

        if(handler != null){
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }

    private void vibrate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "vibrate");

        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;
        vibe.vibrate(500);
    }


    public void initHandler(){

          handler = new Handler();
          runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    processTag();

                }

                private void processTag() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "about to process tag");

                    // parse to records
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            List<Record> records = new Message((NdefMessage)messages[i]);

                            Log.e(TAG, "Found " + records.size() + " records in message " + i);

                            for(int k = 0; k < records.size(); k++) {
                                Log.e(TAG, " Record #" + k + " is of class " + records.get(k).getClass().getSimpleName());

                                Record record = records.get(k);

                                NdefRecord ndefRecord = record.getNdefRecord();

                                byte[] arr = ndefRecord.getPayload();

                                String payload = new String(arr);

                                payload = payload.substring(3, payload.length());

                                Log.e(TAG, "payload = " + payload);

                                Intent processPayloadIntent = new Intent(NfcActivity.this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
                                processPayloadIntent.putExtra("payload", payload);
                                processPayloadIntent.setAction("NFC"); 
                                processPayloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(processPayloadIntent);


                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Problem parsing message", e);
                        }

                    }

                }
            };

        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `onCreate()` is a perfectly valid way of getting the NFC `Intent`. You will only get `onNewIntent()` if Android is delivering the `Intent` to an already-existing instance of your activity. You need to handle the case where the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` `Intent` is coming into `onCreate()` *as well as* when it is coming into `onNewIntent()`. You can see that in sample apps like [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NFC/SecretAgentMan), which is covered in [a book](https://commonsware.com/Android) that I believe you have. :-)

The other thing that you may wish to consider doing is use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on the activity's manifest entry, to ensure that there is only a single copy of that activity in use. This is also shown in the same sample app.

Comment: :) yes i do have your book don't i. I've ameneded the manifest and added the ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED code to onCreate. I'm not sure if that is what you meant? onCreate is still not processing the NFC tag and onNewIntent is still running. Why is this when the NFC code is now in onCreate and OnNewIntent?

Comment: Sorry Mark, i missed the NDEF_DISCOVERED part. It scans first time now. I'll post the full code now, if you wouldn't mind checking if it has been implemented as you have suggested? If i scan the Tag twice in quick succession, then onNewIntent runs and the app freezes. I don't want the tag to be processed twice, so should i just remove the code that processes the tag from onNewIntent?

Comment: @turtleboy: "if you wouldn't mind checking if it has been implemented as you have suggested?" -- I'd have a common implementation of the business logic you duplicated between `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`. "I don't want the tag to be processed twice, so should i just remove the code that processes the tag from onNewIntent?" -- what if the user wants to process two different tags, not in quick succession, but while your app is still running? Better that you figure out where and why you are freezing.

Comment: I've posted the code changes i have now in edit 3. I have placed the NFC capture code in onCreate. onCreate then changes the view, processes the tag and sends the contents to another Activity to send to server. onNewIntent merely calls this same Activity but with a different action, so not to process the tag data or send to server. The reason behind this is my app is for the care industry. Carers scan tags at client's house to log them into calls. so a carer may scan in at 10am then scan out at 11am. if she mis-scans at 10am, i don't want the app to log her in then out immediatly

Comment: i've tried scanning tag A then Tag B and it seems to work correctly. Would edit 3 be a good solution?

Comment: @turtleboy: I am skeptical that basing behavior based upon whether `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()` is called will prove to be reliable in the field. If rapid scans of the same tag is a problem, detect rapid scans (time) of the same tag (content) and filter those out. The determination of whether `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()` is called is based on environment (e.g., did the carer get a text message during the intervening hour?), and therefore you should not be considering one to have a semantic meaning that the other does not.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've implemented a timer in the Application object that starts when a tag is found. In oncreate and onNewIntent i process the tag if conditions are correct. so both onCreate and onNewIntent have the same semantic meaning now. Can i ask one last question, i've noticed that when oncreate runs the action of the intent is android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED whereas when i scan a tag twice (so that onNewIntent runs), the action is android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED. Any ideas why. i'll post the new code if you want it. Thanks for your help.